# IBM Connection changing document owner

Tags: connection, fileapi

Hi I'm trying to change the document owner of a document located in a connection library (v 5.5), I'm still waiting for a reply from IBM but probably is going to take too long for me, that's why I'll try to reverse engineer.

**I tried with the standard editor POST request changing Editor to Owner:**

```
   http://ecm2mydomain.com/dm/atom/library/{id}/document/{id}/members/feed?membershipTimestamp=1456418747000

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <isSecurityInherited xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">false</isSecurityInherited>
    <entry>
        <role xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">Reader</role>
        <uid xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">$IC-T-I-a</uid>
        <securityAction xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">ADD</securityAction>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <role xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">Reader</role>
        <uid xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">$IC-C-M-e43da535-c2bb-4206-9d04-637ad878374b</uid>
        <securityAction xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">ADD</securityAction>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <role xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">Owner</role>
        <uid xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">id</uid>
        <securityAction xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">ADD</securityAction>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

it returns:
404

and is not working, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, is not possible to change the owner since the document on CCM will be owned by community group and the creator of the document.

If you want to add somebody as document owner you have to add it to the community owner group, the original creator is only readable!